# Migrating from MariaDB to Mysql - Duplicate Constraint Name

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb, data-migration

I am trying to migrate a MariaDB database to MySQL. To do this I have created a `mysqldump` of the MariaDB database and am attempting to import into MySQL. (This is being done with the official docker container `mysql:latest`).

I am getting the following error when importing into MySQL:

```
ERROR 3822 (HY000) at line 172: Duplicate check constraint name 'CONSTRAINT_1'.
```

If I look at the `mysqldump` file I can see why this is happening. All boolean columns in my database have a constraints that looks something like:

```
CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` CHECK (`bool_col_1` in (0,1))
CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_2` CHECK (`bool_col_2` in (0,1))
CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_3` CHECK (`bool_col_3` in (0,1))
```

These constraints were not explicitly created by me but implicitly by Flask-SQLAlchemy (I think).

Notice how the constraint names are incremented starting with `CONSTRAINT_1`. Well the problem is that each table starts incrementing its constraint names starting with `CONSTRAINT_1`. Thus the error I am seeing gets thrown when trying to create the second table.

**I'd like to know how best to solve this while keeping the integrity of my database intact.**

Comment: Would this be an issue with `mysqldump`?

Comment: After further research I found that constraints can have the same name as long as they are in different tables. This is valid in MySQL 8.x and MariaDB 10.3 as well. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dGv5iw2FaXiMMRBVV1czkF/0 I'm thinking maybe there's a configuration setting in the destination (MySQL) database that's preventing duplicate names. If there is, maybe it could be turned off.

Comment: Interesting. Looking through the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) it states - "CHECK constraint names must be unique per schema; no two tables in the same schema can share a CHECK constraint name". I don't know how to remedy that with the fiddle you linked, which obviously works.

Comment: Maybe you can get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com since stackoverflow is for programming questions, rather than administration ones.

Comment: You are probably right. Thanks for you help!